# What happens to Quantum computing if Schroedingers equation gets a correction term to account for some new changes in fundamental physics?

Tags: foundations

We all know the current form of Schroedinger's equation. Due to some new observations, let's say it gets modified in a way that a correction term gets added. What are the ramifications for Quantum computing?

Note  I am not talking about relativistic or other corrections already present.

Comment: I have voted to close. While this is an *excellent* question to consider about the foundations of the field, it is both too broad (what sort of modification to the Schrödinger equation?) and inherently about speculative physics (in that it asks about what happens if reality is not governed by quantum theory as we understand it).

Comment: Still think of the same way other corrections work now. They are small corrections. If the new observation is of a phenomenon at energy scale M, then you get small numbers like m/M suppressing corrections. Think of what happens to effective terms when you integrate out a heavy particle and it running around loops becomes a correction.

Comment: I agree with @NieldeBeaudrap that this question is very broad.  There *is* an answer to a narrower question - if Schrödinger's equation is allowed to have any non-linearities at all, an old paper of [Abrams and Lloyd](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9801041) shows that a "quantum" computer can solve NP-complete problems (and #P problems) in polynomial time.